# Using more than two coroutines

Tags: scheme, coroutine, continuations

So I have the following "cor.scm"

```
(define (range-gen str stp inc)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (yield)
     (yield (lambda ()
              (let ([i str])
            (cond ([< str stp]
                   (set! str (+ i inc))
                   i)
                  (else #f))))))))

(define continue? (range-gen 0 10 1))

(define it (range-gen 0 10 1))

(define (routine-a cc)
  (let loop ()
    (cond ((continue?)
       (printf "Blah ~A~N" (it))
       (set! cc (call/cc cc))
       (loop)))))

(define (routine-b cc)
  (let loop ()
    (cond ((continue?)
       (printf "Blar ~A~N" (it))
       (set! cc (call/cc cc))
       (loop)))))
```

Routine-a and b are coroutines. I would like to have a third(nth) routine that would go in cycle, or some other control scheme, i.e a->b->c...->c until the end conditions are met, or even a->b->a->c..a->c.

EDIT:
The output from calling `(routine-a routine-b)` is:

```
; loading cor.scm ...

1> (routine-a routine-b) ;Starts coroutines, notice how they use the continue?
Blah 0                   ;generator to share state, only going through the cycle
Blar 1                   ;5 times each out of the total 10 continue? calls that
Blah 2                   ;will return true.
Blar 3
Blah 4
Blar 5
Blah 6
Blar 7
Blah 8
Blar 9
2> (routine-a routine-b) ;returns nothing, the continue generator now will only return #f
3>                       ;which is the expected behaivor :)
```

Also, whats the best way of passing data between the two coroutines? Right now I would use a variable in the scope of both functions and allow them to mutate its state(which is what im doing with the `continue` generator to keep track of what cycle this is) but I would like to just pass the values if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. in particular, always include the output and error message, if any.

Comment: Its not about the output of this function, although this is correct scheme code. I am talking about coroutines of this form in general and what are the best, idiomatic ways of implementing coroutines in scheme.

Comment: I will add the output though